# Ubuntu 20.04 background -- is there a way to make the screensaver rotate/change every five minutes?

Tags: screensaver, desktop-background

I would like to rotate/change screen saver on my background on Ubuntu 20.04.

Is there a way to have it change/rotate every five minutes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Askubuntu!

To change screensaver every 5 mins:

Go to super > type Screensaver >  click on (In my case its a monitor icon with a moon) Screen saver  Prefs. > there you can customize the time, picture, type of screensaver, etc.

Hope this helps!

Regards.

Comment: Do the settings have an option to set the screensaver (or background) to automatically change every few minutes? Maybe a screenshot of the dialog would be good, if so

Comment: I couldn't find the dialog either.

Comment: @Zanna Sure; I can try to screenshot it :) thanks for pointing out